# Moment.js timezone valueOf returning wrong timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs, milliseconds

I want to use moment.js to shift an input moment to a different timezone and get its timestamp.

```
moment.tz(moment(), "Pacific/Auckland").valueOf();
```

The problem is, while I am doing this, the `moment.tz(`) object is looking good, but the `valueOf()` method is somehow calculating this back to timezone which is set on my computer.

What is wrong with my approach?

Thanks very much.

**EDIT 1**

`moment.tz(moment(), "Pacific/Auckland").format();`
is giving me the right time string

`moment.tz(moment(), "Pacific/Auckland").valueOf("x");`
is giving me the milliseconds, but again in my local time and not in "Pacific/Auckland" time

So somehow the calculation of milliseconds is converting it back to the local time, but why? And whats the correct approach to get the milliseconds in the expected timezone?

Comment: As a rule, numeric timestamps are in always in UTC.  No amount of fiddling with time zones will change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might just be a conceptual lack of understanding of what the timestamp actually is.

Let's say the current time where I am is:

04/25/2016 @ 10:21am (UTC-7)

What is the timestamp of this moment?

1461604867

What is the UTC time?

04/25/2016 @ 5:21pm (UTC)

What is the timestamp of this moment?

**1461604867**

What, the same, why?

**A moment in time is the same timestamp, regardless of which timezone it is in.** When you call moment(), it is referring to right NOW, this particular moment in time in the grand space-time continuum. Same with Date.now(). The moment you are reading this is, in reality, still the exact same moment where you are, where I am, in Japan, in Antarctica, in Syria, in Greenland, etc. It just so happens that this one moment is visually represented (the time string) by humans in different ways in each area.

Moment timezone does not affect the actual Date object it stores. It only affects the *visual representation of the date.* The visual representation varies across timezone. That is why you will not get a different timestamp.

Comment: That's a very good answer.  I would like to tweak it just a bit.  moment timezone does affect the date object it stores if you're converting a string to a particular time zone.  If my computer is in London, and I want to get a timestamp for a transaction in New York at 5pm, I have to specify the timezone or calculate the offset myself or I'll get an incorrect timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
var time  = moment.tz("2016-04-25 12:00", "Pacific/Auckland");
```

then

```
time.format();
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks for your relpy.

`time.format()`

is giving me the correct string, but i need to get a millisecond timestamp. Why is

`.valueOf()` giving another value than `.format()`?

Comment: than try,moment().millisecond()

Comment: Not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `.valueOf()` is always milliseconds in UTC.

You can convert the milliseconds back to your desired time-zone like this:

```
  const moment= Moment(milliseconds)
  moment.tz(TIME_ZONE).format("LT")
```